# ionicModal not generating a modal on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a login modal open on application start. This works properly in Chrome simulation, but not on my LG G3 with Android 5 (if that matters).

The code (for now) is based heavily on the sidemenu starter, which works.

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/app/login/login.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    backdropClickToClose: false,
    hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
    focusFirstInput: true
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.login();
  });

  $scope.login = function () {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
```

The `then` part is not executed, leaving `$scope.modal` as undefined (checked with setting some `$scope` variable in it and printing it in the view and also trying to print `$scope.modal` in the view - neither are changed).

Additionally, calling the `login` function with `ng-click` doesn't work as well, obviously.

Any ideas about the disparity? Is it some setting? Or something in the code? Or something else?

**Edit:**
Additional tidbit, if it matters: the code is in a self-executing anonymous function:

```
(function () {

  angular.module('module')

    .controller('controller', [
      '$scope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout',
      function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

    ...

    }]);
})();
```

Comment: Any chance it's your path? Can you try `'login/login.html'`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no (I've checked) - as I've mentioned, it works correctly in simulation in Chrome with this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of ionic, a leading slash can be an issue when loading on the device, but still work in the browser. Can you try: `app/login/login.html` (without the leading `/`).

Comment: You are correct! It's weird, but working. :) Do you happen to know why is that? Some internal offsets in the APK?

Comment: I don't know the technical details, but I think it's related to the way the APK is packaged, different file directory structure for a device.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks again! :)